# can an IP address be used in YAML

Tags: yaml

```
---
- hosts: 192.168.1.1
  tasks:
  - name: run show version on remote devices
   ios_command:
     commands: show version
```

> Error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column
>   9

What exactly have I done wrong with this syntax? Is it possible to use a IP here instead of DNS?

Comment: You may want to try escaping the IP (saying explicitly that it's a string) : hosts: "192.168.1.1"

Comment: You need to indent your YAML properly.

Comment: the line `ios_command:` needs to be indented by one more space

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use an IP like `192.168.1.1`, it will be recognised as a string (during parsing as soon as the second dot is encountered, which makes it a not a floating point number.

The problem in your file is in the indentation of `ios_command` its `i` has to align with the `n` from `name`:

```
---
- hosts: 192.168.1.1
  tasks:
  - name: run show version on remote devices
    ios_command:
     commands: show version
```